# meta-qt5 Krogoth Branch Building Error During 'do_populate_sysroot'

Tags: qt5, yocto, qtwebengine

I am trying to build 'meta-qt5 krogoth branch' but I am getting following error during qtwebengine 'do_populate_sysroot' state.

> ERROR: qtwebengine-5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0 do_populate_sysroot: QA Issue: Qt5WebEngineCore.pc failed sanity test (tmpdir) in path /home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/pkgconfig [pkgconfig]
>
> ERROR: qtwebengine-5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0 do_populate_sysroot: QA staging was broken by the package built above
>
> ERROR: qtwebengine-5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0 do_populate_sysroot: Function failed: do_qa_staging
>   ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sysroot.2443
>
> ERROR: Task 878 (/home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtwebengine_git.bb, do_populate_sysroot) failed with exit code '1'

And this is 'log.do_populate_sysroot.2443' file:

> DEBUG: Executing python function sstate_task_prefunc
>
> DEBUG: Python function sstate_task_prefunc finished
>
> DEBUG: Executing python function do_populate_sysroot
>
> DEBUG: Executing shell function sysroot_stage_all
>
> 0 blocks
>
> 0 blocks
>
> 0 blocks
>
> DEBUG: Shell function sysroot_stage_all finished
>
> DEBUG: Executing python function sysroot_strip
>
> DEBUG: runstrip: 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note --strip-unneeded '/home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5.6.1'
>
> DEBUG: runstrip: 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note '/home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/share/qt5/examples/webenginewidgets/markdowneditor/markdowneditor'
>
> DEBUG: runstrip: 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note '/home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/share/qt5/examples/webenginewidgets/contentmanipulation/contentmanipulation'
>
> DEBUG: runstrip: 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note --strip-unneeded '/home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/qt5/qml/QtWebEngine/experimental/libqtwebengineexperimentalplugin.so'
>
> DEBUG: runstrip: 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note '/home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/share/qt5/examples/webenginewidgets/simplebrowser/simplebrowser'
>
> DEBUG: runstrip: 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note '/home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/share/qt5/examples/webengine/minimal/minimal'
>
> DEBUG: runstrip: 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note '/home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/qt5/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess'
>
> DEBUG: runstrip: 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note '/home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/share/qt5/examples/webenginewidgets/minimal/minimal'
>
> DEBUG: runstrip: 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note '/home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/share/qt5/examples/webenginewidgets/demobrowser/demobrowser'
>
> DEBUG: runstrip: 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note --strip-unneeded '/home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5.6.1'
>
> DEBUG: runstrip: 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note --strip-unneeded '/home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/libQt5WebEngine.so.5.6.1'
>
> DEBUG: runstrip: 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note '/home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/share/qt5/examples/webengine/quicknanobrowser/quicknanobrowser'
>
> DEBUG: runstrip: 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note --strip-unneeded '/home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/qt5/qml/QtWebEngine/libqtwebengineplugin.so'
>
> DEBUG: Python function sysroot_strip finished
>
> DEBUG: Python function do_populate_sysroot finished
>
> DEBUG: Executing python function do_qa_staging
>
> NOTE: QA checking staging
>
> ERROR: QA Issue: Qt5WebEngineCore.pc failed sanity test (tmpdir) in path /home/yusuf/yocto-krogoth/poky/qt5Toolchain/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.6.0+gitAUTOINC+643aa579fc_8252b18aa3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/pkgconfig [pkgconfig]
>
> ERROR: QA staging was broken by the package built above
>
> DEBUG: Python function do_qa_staging finished
>
> ERROR: Function failed: do_qa_staging

What is cause of this problem? How do I fix this?

Comment: As far as I see, the error is not being caused by QtWebengine but being caused when bitbake is scheduling qtwebengine for compilation. You see the sanity error at the start. This is because the paths might have changed due to some unseen modification. Now, just remove the contents of `tmp` folder and then try building again. Hopefully, this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To be exact, the error occurs during executing task do_qa_staging().

Similar issue has been raised on openembedded list in March: [[oe] [meta-qt5][PATCH] qtbase: fix up pkgconfig replacements](http://lists.openembedded.org/pipermail/openembedded-devel/2016-March/106290.html). You can see that in it was responded that:

> I tested with qtwebengine
>   PV="5.5.99+5.6.0-rc+gitAUTOINC+3f02c25de4_779a2388fc" and it is
>   working.

Then OP wrote that he just simply removed the meta-luneui layer (can be done by changing the value of BBLAYERS variable in bblayers.conf file in your build/conf/ directory).

Also this [patch](http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/commit/meta/classes/insane.bbclass?id=3739aaf644d5a0f28e85fd07c67cecbfa5b8fb8a) seems to be a fix for this issue.

As you are facing this issue I suggest that you should try with qtwebengine in version 5.5 and see what's the result. To try it, as quoted above, change the value of PV variable in qtwebengine_git.bb recipe.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I built jethro branch(qt 5.5) successfully. But webengine did not work smoothly on target platform. It couldn't show page.So I hope that version 5.6 can work without any problem. I will try to path your path file.

Comment: Yeah, hope you will find appropriate solution. You can also check the Yocto project bugzilla if similar issues have been raised: https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/. And if not, consider adding a new ticket with details about your issue.